# set data only on first load with nuxt.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I'm new to nuxt.js so I'm wondering what could be the best way to set up some data via REST api.

I have a store folder like this:

```
store
    -posts.js
    -categories.js
    -index.js
```

I've tried to set the data with `nuxtServerInit` actions in the `index.js`:

```
export const actions = {
    async nuxtServerInit({ dispatch }) {
        await dispatch('categories/setCategories')
        await dispatch('posts/loadPosts','all')
       
        
      }
}
```

But doesn't works: actions are dispatched (on the server) but data are not set.

So I've tried with [fetch](https://nuxtjs.org/api/pages-fetch/) but this method is called every time the page where I have to display posts is loaded. Even if, in the general layout, I do this:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <Header />
    <keep-alive>
      <nuxt/>
    </keep-alive>
    
  </div>
</template>
```

So my solution, for now, is to use fetch in this way,
In the page component:

```
 async fetch({store}){
       if(store.getters['posts/getPosts'].length === 0 && store.getters['categories/getCategories'].length === 0 ){
            await store.dispatch('categories/setCategories')
            await store.dispatch('posts/loadPosts','all')
       } 
   }
```

Also, one thing I noted is that fetch seems not working on the root page component (pages/index.vue)

My solution seems works, but there is maybe another better way to set the data?

Comment: have you tried putting the fetch in the `created` or `mounted` lifecycle hook of the display post component?

Comment: ok the problem was that if I use NuxtServerInit, the actions dispatched by there have to return a promise, so have to begin with 'return': return axios.get() and not simply axios.get()

Answer (score 1):

There's no out of the box solution for this as it's specific to your requirements/needs. My solution is very similar to yours but instead of checking the size of data array I introduced additional variable `loaded` in every store module. I only fetch data if loaded is false. This approach is more suitable in apps that have user generated content and require authentication. It will work optimally with SSR and client-side, and it won't try to fetch data on every page visit if user has no data.

You could also simplify your fetch method like this:

```
async fetch()
{
    await this.$store.dispatch('posts/getOnce')
}
```

Now your posts.js store module will look something like this:

```
export const state = () => ({
    list: [],
    loaded: false
})

export const actions = {
    async getOnce({ dispatch, state }) {
        if (!state.loaded) {
            dispatch('posts/get')
        }
    },
    async get({ commit, state }) {
        await this.$axios.get(`/posts`)
            .then((res) => {
                if (res.status === 200) {
                    commit('set', res.data.posts)
                }
            })
    }         
}

export const mutations = {
    set(state, posts) {
        state.list = posts
        state.loaded = true
    }
}
```